# Error rendering XML/XLS with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xampp, domdocument

I'm working on a final project for school involving XML/XSL and I chose to do it in PHP. I've been using XAMPP to view my website and everything has worked great until I uploaded everything to the schools web server. I don't get any errors on my PHP page, it simply stops rendering when it hits the PHP function call. I'm not sure why everything worked on XAMPP but not on the web server. I apologize if this question has come up before. I looked through other questions but didn't find anything that solved my issue. Thank you in advance for looking!

Here is my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nav>

  <item>
    <name>Home</name>
    <url>index.php</url>
  </item>

  <item>
    <name>What's Inside</name>
    <url>about.php</url>
  </item>

  <item>
    <name>Pod Locations</name>
    <url>pods.php</url>
  </item>

  <item>
    <name>Trail Map</name>
    <url>trail.php</url>
  </item>

  <item>
    <name>Contact Us</name>
    <url>contact.php</url>
  </item>

</nav>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!--
  Process XML
-->
  <xsl:template match="nav/item">
    <li>
      <a href="{url}" class='button'><xsl:value-of select="name"/></a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home - CyclePods</title>

    <?php require('common/header.php'); ?>

    <?php 
      function processXML($source) {
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xsl = new DOMDocument;
        $process = new XSLTProcessor;

        $xml->load('assets/xml/' . $source . '.xml');
        $xsl->load('assets/xml/process.xsl');

        $process->importStyleSheet($xsl);

        echo $process->transformToXML($xml);
      }
    ?>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-span">
      <div class="nav-row">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-back">
      <div class="banner-front">

        <div class="tabs">

          <ul class="horizontal">
            <?php processXML('navigation'); ?> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="background">
      <div class="body">

        <div class="row">


         </div>        

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check if there is a version mismatch of PHP and ask the school it admin for the error log.

Comment: I looked into it and found that I am running 5.5.9 and the school is running 5.3.8. When I talked to the Admin he said that he "doesn't release that info to students"

Comment: I feel your pain. Wrap your code into a try catch and print back the error to the browser (try catch is slang for error handling routine). You might want to use the older version to test.

Comment: If you are in for an argument, print the list of security flaws in 5.3.8 and hand it to your admin :-)

Comment: Gave it a shot, no errors, it simply doesn't render just like any other time.

Comment: The code shown should be fine in 5.3.8 - perhaps there's something in common/header.php that's causing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code is valid, it just requires newer versions of PHP. Uploaded my project to a free host (with the most recent version of PHP) and it worked like a charm.